# Wix Coded drop-down menu getting stuck

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, hover, velo

I'm having an issue with this drop down menu for a nav bar that I've made in Wix code - what I've got does work but it seems to be getting a bit stuck - in that, the drop down menus that should be disappearing once you move away at times do, and at times just stay up there?

Here's a link that will demonstrate it:
https://loughtonbaptist.wixsite.com/site

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

My code is:

```
export function button12_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu1').show('glide',{ "duration": 100, "delay": 100, "angle": 180, "distance": 20 }); 
}

export function button12_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu1').hide(); 
}

export function menu1_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu1').show();
$w('#button12').disable() 
}

export function menu1_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu1').hide();
$w('#button12').enable() 
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

export function button16_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu2').show('glide',{ "duration": 100, "delay": 0, "angle": 180, "distance": 20 }); 
}

export function menu2_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu2').hide();
$w('#button16').enable() 
}

export function button16_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu2').hide(); 
}

export function menu2_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu2').show();
$w('#button16').disable() 
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

export function button20_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu3').show('glide',{ "duration": 100, "delay": 0, "angle": 180, "distance": 20 }); 
}

export function button20_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu3').hide(); 
}

export function menu3_onmouseIn(event) {
$w('#menu3').show();
$w('#button20').disable() 
}

export function menu3_onmouseOut(event) {
$w('#menu3').hide();
$w('#button20').enable() 
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem only happens when the mouseOut event triggers while the mouseIn event's show animation is still running. you can confirm that by temporarily removing the show animation. Let me know if you confirm that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes if I remove the animation from the code then it's fine, I can apply an animation to the drop down menu the normal way instead, but the only slight annoyance is it only happens once.. for some reason Wix doesn't keep animating it, it just animates one time and only if you reload the page it will animate again.  Not a big problem of course, I can live with it, but it would be nice to keep that animation going.. I don't suppose that's possible?